# PHP $_SESSION data getting mixed

Tags: php, session, development-environment

I'm running into a situation on my site where a user logs in, and then whichever user logs in next, the first users sees their $_SESSION data.

Any ideas what could be causing this? The site is on a shared HostGator environment. Is there some sort of caching that could be causing users to login and be assigned the same PHPSESSID?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: @JeffC This is obviously some kind of PHP configuration issue. I don't think there's any amount of code he could post that would make it better.

Comment: I was thinking it was a PHP configuration issue as well.

This happened all of a sudden this week after HostGator said they had to cache my site due to a CPU spike. It's been days and the caching should have gone away, but I am left with this issue.

Comment: @Barmar I will defer to your substantial PHP rep... :) I just see questions like this with no code listed and immediately ask for it.

Comment: I think what they're saying is that they're not running your PHP scripts. They've cached the results of the script, so everyone just sees the same content. This is totally useless for a dynamic site, you need to get a better hosting provider.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks a ton for your thoughts on this. This is exactly what I was thinking too, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't likely that it would happen via code. I've been telling this company for a couple years to find a better host. Maybe now they will listen.

Comment: If you're causing a CPU spike, you might also need to check your scripts to make sure it's not too inefficient. Also check your hit rate, maybe you need to upgrade to a higher service level for the quantity of traffic you're getting.

Comment: @Barmar - It usually purrs along at around 3%. I've been keeping an eye on TOP. We got a ton of hits all of a sudden and maxed out earlier this week. This has happened once or twice before, but never with this annoying results after. Definitely looking into a host that will be able to handle us even if we have traffic spikes. I reached out to support 3 days ago and they still haven't updated my ticket once.

Comment: That's another red flag! Well, I hope they're cheap -- you get what you pay for.